# Yii1 access model class using 2nd database connection. Multiple database connection

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii1.x

I've used multiple database connection.

main.php

```
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    'db2'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=remotelocalhost;dbname=seconddb',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class'=>'CDbConnection'
        ),
    ),
)
```

When model class used the second database connection(remote database - db2) record is not updated

Plz help me to resolve this issue.

**Model Class**

```
class Modelclass extends CActiveRecord
{
    // model class code
}
```

Comment: how are you using the connection.....could u please post some more code

Comment: finally I find out the solution. thanks lakshay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access multiple database connection in Yii1

Below are the steps:

**Step1: Create database connection string in config/main.php**

```
'components'=>array(
    'db2'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=RemoteHostIpAddress;dbname=Remote_DB_Name',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'Remote_DB_User_Name',
        'password' => 'Remote_DB_Password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
    ),

    'db'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_Name',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'DB_User_Name',
        'password' => 'DB_Password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
    ),
)
```

**Step2: Create new class in components to access 2nd database connection(db2)**

```
class Db2ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static $db2;

    public function getDbConnection()
    {

        if(self::$db2!==null)
            return self::$db2;
        else
        {
            self::$db2=Yii::app()->db2;
            self::$db2->connectionString;

            if(self::$db2 instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                self::$db2->setActive(true);
                return self::$db2;
            }
            else{
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Step3: extends the model class from 2nd database using class created in components**

```
class Modelclass extends Db2ActiveRecord
{
    // model class code
}
```